# Correct syntax-highlighting on Subroutine Signatures in vim

Tags: perl, vim

I have perl 5.22 (with subroutine signatures) and vim 7.4.1689. (These come standard on Ubuntu 16.04)

When I type subroutine signatures in the definition of a subroutine, I get the signature in red background, as if I typed something wrong that won't get accepted by perl.

perl runs my code fine, however.

How do I fix vim to accept the signature and not highlight it as an error?

```
sub sum($s, $t) {
    print $s+$t, "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preliminary support for signature highlighting was [added](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl/pull/151) in February, 2014, with [another tweak](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl/issues/166) in July, 2014. The Perl syntax file that came with my Vim 7.4 install says it was last changed in 2013, so you'll probably need to update.

Install the latest version of [vim-perl](https://github.com/vim-perl/vim-perl/tree/master) and add the following to your .vimrc:

```
let perl_sub_signatures = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Placing this file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim-perl/vim-perl/master/syntax/perl.vim in my ~/.vim/syntax folder and adding the line you said in ~/.vimrc fixed my problem!